# How can I let images uploaded via ckeditor show their full url in a json request via REST?

Tags: wysiwyg, 8

I have textarea fields in my headless drupal 8 site. When I get the node via REST in json it does not give the domain name in the image urls that are uploaded via ckeditor. So the images are not shown when I display this field.

Answer (score 1):

You can relatively easily fix the images on the client using jQuery by following [Correct Img Src Path with Javascript and Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189191/correct-img-src-path-with-javascript-and-jquery).

Comment: Thanks, I actually already did something similar in the mean time. But it feels hackish and not like a proper solution.

Comment: Using embedded images in fields in a headless context is probably not wise as you have no control on image size either. I prefer image fields as ie my angular can either fetch the images or add an image style to them depending on device. btw please + vote my answer :p

Comment: That's the worst approach you can consider.

Comment: @otarza please elaborate on that.

Comment: You suggested replacing all image sources on client side, which is just not good idea for many reasons. On the other hand this approach requires to replace sources on every client using the service. Service should provide correct urls to images and its not clients job to determine where is image, it should just render. Anyway solving this on server is simple and will prevent any further problems.

Answer (score 0):

`CKEditor` uses relative urls and that's right, because if service URL changes for some reason urls must not be hardcoded, otherwise image urls will become invalid.

You can impement
[hook_entity_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_load/8) and edit your field's value using regular expression.

UPDATE:

To prevent hardcoding of website's url, you can use [$base_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21globals.api.php/global/base_url/8) global in `hook_entity_load`.

Comment: That would contradict you "urls must not be hardcoded" and the fix is only needed for REST. It probably breaks CK Editor later on when configured to only accept relative path too.

Comment: No that's not true.

[$base_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21globals.api.php/global/base_url/8) global can be used in `hook_entity_load` to prevent hardcoding.